# ASP.NET Web API : An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, client-certificates

Web Api

```
[HttpGet]
[RequireHttps]
[Route("Api/GetString")]
public string GetString()
{
   return "Worked";
}
```

RequireHttpsAttribute class

```
public class RequireHttpsAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.Request.RequestUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeHttps)
        {
            actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
            {
                ReasonPhrase = "HTTPS Required"
            };
        }
        else
        {
            var cert = actionContext.Request.GetClientCertificate();
            if (cert == null)
            {
                actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
                {
                    ReasonPhrase = "Client Certificate Required"
                };

            }
            base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Client (console)

```
HttpWebRequest client = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://localhost:44315/api/GetString");
var cert = new X509Certificate2(File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\ConsoleClient\TestCertificate.pfx"), "password");
client.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)client.GetResponse();
using (var readStream = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
{
   Console.WriteLine(readStream.ReadToEnd());
}
```

This https request throws error.

```
Inner Exception Message : Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
Message : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
```

I opened port 443 and tried some settings mentioned in answers of same type of questions but couldn't resolve. Direct access to https://localhost:44315/api/GetString via browser is also not working.

If I change the https to http, it works fine.

Is anything needs to be configured?

Thanks.

Comment: Try removing your custom attribute to see if it's working without it over https.

Comment: If I remove [RequireHttps] and access the same method via Http it works.

Comment: Try remove and access via **https**. It might tell that the problem is with your attribute.

Comment: @AndriiLitvinov Thanks for the suggestion but it behaves same.

Comment: Works same in browser or with your client? Try create new web api project and make sure it works with https in browser. Then incrementally add new feature to it to narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was updating the https protocol from the default ssl3 to tls via https://stackoverflow.com/a/46223433/352432