# c# .net 8 posting large collection va web api httpost gets SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-8.0

Im trying to post a large list of (object) to a web api in .net 8. If I post 1000 records it works fine but when I do a larger list i get a SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

my webapi  is

```
        [HttpPost("ImportBranchAppointments/{ApiKey},{BranchCode}")]

        public async Task<ActionResult<int>> ImportBranchAppointmentsAsync(string ApiKey, string BranchCode, [FromBody] List<AppointmentModel> BranchApptHistory)
        {

            var OrgGuid = ValidateApiKey(ApiKey);

            if (OrgGuid == "")
            {
                return Unauthorized("Invalid API key");

            }

            try
            {
                var Count = await _ImportService.ImportBranchAppointmentsHist(ApiKey, BranchCode, BranchApptHistory);

                return Ok(Count);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, $"Internal server error {ex.Message}");
            }

        }
```

and im calling it from a winform app.

```
        private async Task<int> RunAppointEaseAppointmentHistoryImport(string AppointeaseDB, int DocNum, string BranchCode, HttpClient client, string ApiKey)
        {
            var ApptEaseAppointments = new List<AppointEaseAppointment>();

          
            // get data
            ApptEaseAppointments = DbImport.GetAppointmentsDataFromAppointEaseODBC(AppointeaseDB, DocNum).ToList();

            try
            {
                var Data = MapAppointeaseAppointmentHistory(ApptEaseAppointments, BranchCode);

                string customersJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(Data.Take(3));
                // Convert the list to a JSON string to test in swagger
              
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                var Result = await client.PostAsJsonAsync($"api/ImportData/ImportBranchAppointments/{ApiKey},{BranchCode}", Data);

                Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
              
                // Check if the request was successful (HTTP 200 OK)
                if (Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    // Parse the response content to get the count
                    //  int count2 = await Result.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<int>();
                    int count = await Result.Content.ReadAsAsync<int>();
                    return count;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Handle the error response if need
                    // MessageBox.Show (Result.Content.)
                    throw new Exception($"API request failed with status code: {Result.StatusCode}");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex.Message);
                throw;
            }

        }
```

the webapi is hosted in Blazor app.
I could iterate through it and make multiple posts to the webservice but was wondering if there a better way.
Any Help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you using a static HttpClient ? if somewhere you are creating a new HttpClient it creates a new socket

Comment: The remote host has probably a limit on the receive size.

Comment: Its sounds a little like socket exhaustion. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests

Comment: Did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46223433/20240963 ?

Comment: Does the problem go away if you decorate the controller method with either `[RequestSizeLimit(your_size_in_bytes)]` or `[DisableRequestSizeLimit()]` - example here https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/49594